# How to get metrics object within the result of N1QL query through PHP SDK

Tags: php, couchbase, sql++

Can I get the metrics object of the following N1QL query within the result

```
$myBucket = $myCluster->openBucket();
$myBucket->enableN1ql(array('http://1.1.1.1:8093/','http://1.1.1.2:8093/'));
$query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT * FROM default');
$res = $myBucket->query($query);
var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls check following post.. it suggests a solution:  https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-get-metrics-within-the-result-of-n1ql-query-through-php-sdk/8440